# Django Class based views - Signup

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have implemented a SignUp/SignIn based on class based views. While the Login is working fine, Sign up it does not. The problem is that after trying to register user and POST method is 200, user is not created in database.
BTW I think the problem is on the FrontEnd because when i'm using a simple html file with `{{ form.as_p }}` it works when i'm using a template from internet it does not.
Please help me to identify the reason:

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class UserResisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    success_message = "Your profile was created successfully"
```

authapp1/urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserResisterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserResisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

auth/urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    # Django authentication system with package URLs
    path('authapp1/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('authapp1/', include('authapp1.urls')),
```

html template

```
<!-- Register -->
<section class="our-log-reg bgc-fa">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                <div class="sign_up_form inner_page">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Register to start learning</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Have an account? <a class="text-thm" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <form action="{% url 'register' %}" form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword4" placeholder="Password" name="password1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword5" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck3">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck3">Want to become an instructor?</label>
                            </div>
                            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-log btn-block btn-thm2">Register</button>
                            <div class="divide">
                                <span class="lf_divider">Or</span>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt40">
                                <div class="col-lg">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block color-white bgc-fb mb0"><i class="fa fa-facebook float-left mt5"></i> Facebook</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn2 btn-block color-white bgc-gogle mb0"><i class="fa fa-google float-left mt5"></i> Google</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Login template that works fine:

```
<!-- LogIn -->
    <section class="our-log bgc-fa">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                    <div class="login_form inner_page">
                        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="heading">
                                <h3 class="text-center">Login to your account</h3>
                                <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a class="text-thm" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up!</a></p>
                            </div>
                            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword4" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck3">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck3">Remember me</label>
                                <a class="tdu btn-fpswd float-right" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-log btn-block btn-thm2">Login</button>
                            <div class="divide">
                                <span class="lf_divider">Or</span>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt40">
                                <div class="col-lg">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block color-white bgc-fb mb0"><i class="fa fa-facebook float-left mt5"></i> Facebook</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn2 btn-block color-white bgc-gogle mb0"><i class="fa fa-google float-left mt5"></i> Google</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the form using:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

If it doesn't work still, paste the request body that is sent with the form, so we can check it out.
If it works it means that your inputs have wrong names/ids.

Edit: the field names are incorrect:

```
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword4" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            </div>
```

to become:

```
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword4" placeholder="Password" name="password1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword4" placeholder="Password" name="password2">
                            </div>
```

Edit 2: Added references
UserCreationForm has "password1" and "password2" as mandatory fields.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/

Comment: Thank you! I tried to render form as {{ form.as_p }} and it works fine. Do you know how can i set these names/ids correctly?

Comment: I think you're missing the password confirmation field. Do you see more fields when you render the form that way?

Comment: Thank you again. I have already tested with the password1 and password2 but it doesn't work either. I checked the field names by inspecting the {{form.as_p}} form which works fine. It's weird.

Comment: Compare the request bodies from the 2 different templates using the network tab on your  dev tools

Comment: My guess is that you also have a trailing "/" missing on the form `action` with your template

Comment: The difference i see is in the status code 302 when successful and 200 when is not.

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/authapp1/register/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin

With template

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/authapp1/register/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin

csrfmiddlewaretoken: 5TcpQzOfc1xqBJ9gbeEhEhYz2dDdGJUpjMYODkGn2p6QX7rbi72FIOeOsVoNAf5P
username: cristiano
password1: 1qaz2wsx!QAZ@WSX
password2: 1qaz2wsx!QAZ@WSX

Comment: Can you show me with code what do you mean trailing "/" missing of the form action with your template?

Comment: This line when it's rendered probably has 2 different actions <form action="{% url 'register' %}" form method="POST">